# Load components dynamically in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to load components dynamically which means I don't know which component to load during compile time. 
I have read about DynamicComponentLoader [here](https://medium.com/tixdo-labs/angular-2-dynamic-component-loader-752c3235bf9#.q82obw1g0)  but the [angular2 Api docs](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) says this class is deprecated, so what is the current/correct way to do this?

Comment: See this Günter's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 and also his topic in documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/831/dynamically-add-components-using-viewcontainerref-createcomponent/2813/a-wrapper-component-that-adds-dynamic-components-declaratively#t=201607240546278053969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ComponentResolver` and `ViewContainerRef` as a replacement for `DynamicComponentLoader`